# Time Stamp and byte array

Tags: c++, timestamp, arrays

I'm trying to insert a timestamp (hour:min:sec) into a two-byte array and i'm a little confused on how to accomplish this...any help is greatly appreciated!

```
int Hour = CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetHour(); 
int Minute = CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetMinute(); 
int Second = CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetSecond(); 

BYTE arry[2];

//Need to insert 'Hour', 'Minute', & 'Second' into 'arry'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  There are potentially 86402 seconds in a day (a day can have up to two leap seconds), but the 16 bits available to you in a `byte[2]` array can only represent 65536 separate values.

Comment: A day cannot have more than one leap second (no matter what the documentation for `gmtime()` and friends states -- the POSIX committee screwed up bigtime on this one).

Comment: How could I accomplish this if I could increase the size of my byte array?

Comment: if you want to use an 8 character array you use:  sprintf(arry, "%d:%d:%d", Hour, Minute, Second);  But that is old style C code.  It should work for you if you have 9 bytes (8 plus one for null)

Comment: If you had three bytes, you could just store it with hours at index 0, minutes at index 1, and seconds at index 2.

Comment: So, I could do something like this?

BYTE arry[9];
sprintf(arry, "%d:%d:%d", Hour, Minute, Second);

Answer (score 1):

1. hour:min:sec is not what people call timestamp. A timestamp is the number of seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01 and will surely not fit into 16 bits.
2. Assuming ranges of hours=[0;24], minutes=[0;60], seconds=[0;60] (leap seconds included) you will need 5+6+6=17 bits which still won't fit into 16 bits.

If you had a 32-bit array, it would fit:

```
int Hour = CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetHour(); 
int Minute = CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetMinute(); 
int Second = CTime::GetCurrentTime().GetSecond(); 

uint8_t array[4];

// Just an example
*(uint32_t*)array = (Hour << 12) | (Minute << 6) | Second;
```

This sounds somewhat like homework for me... or what is the exact purpose of doing this?

Comment: I need to send out "heartbeat" packet every 30ms in our simulation and as part of this packet, I need to include the "timestamp", that's the purpose of this

Comment: Here is the info. from the ICD

Byte 1 - 2 Bits 15:0 Time Stamp

Time Stamp = Time of message (hearbeat message) creation.